# Partial Fraction Decomposition of unknown power

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, partial-fractions, rational-functions

I have an equation of the form:
$$\frac{1}{(1+as)(1+0.5bs)^m}$$

where $m$ is unknown, and its range is $(1,2,3,...)$
How I can do the partial fraction?

I am now reading a paper that derived an equation like above.
I attached the section of the paper that he did this, but he doesn't mention the steps.
I want to know how this has been done.

Thank you very much.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For any $m$, the form of the partial fraction for your expression is
$$
\frac{1}{(1+as)(1+0.5bs)^m} =\frac{c_0}{1 + as} + \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{c_i}{(1 + 0.5bs)^i}.
$$

You determine the coefficients $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_m$ in the usual way: clear denominators to get a polynomial identity, then evaluate the polynomial identity or an appropriate derivative of the polynomial identity at a well-chosen value of $s$ to make all but two terms vanish.

Comment: Simply, I tried but my calculation is wrong.

Comment: Were you able to clear denominators and plug in $s = -2b$ to solve for $c_0$?  It's hard to know how to reply, because I don't know what specifically in the calculation is causing you difficulty.

Comment: I think the first part is easy. set `s=−1/a` then solve _co_. My problem is in the second part. for example when I set `s=−2/b` for the purpose of solving _ci_

Comment: You have to plug in $s = -2/b$ and you will be able to solve for one of the $c_i$.  Then differentiate both sides with respect to s, and plug in $s = -2/b$, and you'll be able to solve for a different $c_i$.  Keep repeating this process.

Comment: $$
{c_0(1 + 0.5bs)^m} + \sum_{i=1}^m c_i(1 + as)(1+0.5bs)^{m-i} = 1
$$

Comment: but when you set `s=−2/b` the second part which contain **ci** will be zero. so how to differentiate it?

Comment: Differentiate first, then plug in.  Then go back to the pre-plugged in formula and differentiate again, and plug in again, etc.

Comment: the problem is that this term is always remain in the equation after doing the differentioation $$ (1+0.5bs)$$ which make everything zero after substitution of `s=-2/b`
for example when I do the differentioation in the case `i=1` is as the following:
$$

0.5*b*c0{(1+0.5bs)^{m-1}} + c1*(1+as)*0.5*b*{(1+0.5bs)^{m-2}} + c1*{(1+0.5bs)^{m-1}}*a =0
$$
now when you substitute `s=-2/b` everything will be zero.

Comment: is my calculation is wrong? I followed your instructions but I couldn't be able to solve it. do you have any comment?

Comment: I don't follow your comment.  There is no case $i = 1$ because $i$ is an index of summation, not an independent variable.